# Angular JS Filter with all values

Tags: angularjs

I have a grid which is selectable. On Clicking -> Select. I want the selected value to be highlighted and displayed as first value in another grid along with the remaining values I used a angular filter but it is displaying only the selected value.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provided some of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `selected` flag on each item, something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" 
        ng-class="{ selected: item.selected }" 
        ng-click="item.selected = !item.selected">
        {{ item.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{selected:true}" 
        ng-click="item.selected = false">
        {{ item.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgzhmjtm/)

To show the selected ones first in a grid, you can use the `orderBy` filter:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'-selected'" 
        ng-click="item.selected = false">
        {{ item.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgzhmjtm/1/)